# Where can I add or change the options in the system menu?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I want to add another option to the system menu(Alt-Space) in Windows.  What locations in the Windows Registry control the entries on this menu?

[image: Registry]

Comment: Also, make sure to link your SU and SO accounts by clicking on your username at the top of the page and selecting the **Accounts** tab.

Comment: sorry about the duplicates... =p

Answer (score 1):

The system menu can only be changed programmatically.

See my answer on [How to add custom item to system menu in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138616/how-to-add-custom-item-to-system-menu-in-c/138896#138896) from StackOverflow (where this question belongs and shouldn't have been migrated from in the first place).