# how to customize the windows system menu of an existing application

Tags: windows

How can i add an entry in the system menu of any or specific application. An example, there is restore, move, minimize, maximize, close and i would like to add notepad, or a .bat/wmi script.
I'm not asking how to do that in MY application.
I'm asking this for existing applications in my computer.

Comment: Related? - https://superuser.com/q/113554/1062246

Comment: You just need to edit the source code for those applications to include the nedessary changes and then recompile.

Comment: applications in my computer are existing applications from MS and others, i don't have source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SmartSystemMenu
https://github.com/AlexanderPro/SmartSystemMenu
it is a modifiable solution